# Can I run a XAP without IIS?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Can I run a xap without IIS. If I want to install an app on client machines do I have to use an IIS server?

Comment: Are you asking about running your SL app from a web server other than IIS?  Or do you want to run without a web server and do a more traditional application installer?

Comment: To clarify the question. I am looking to install on a client without an IIS server. Basically I don't expect customers to have IIS running on their machine but I'd like to be able to install a Silverlight application to view photos on their machines. Haven't had an opportunity to test the answers yet. Doing that this week.

Answer (score 2):

The most easy way  would be to craft an html page with embedded silverlight referencing your xap locally and make user open your html page.

A complete list of alternative Silverlight hosting mechanisms is provided on the MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550717(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

With the caveat that I haven't actually tried this, *yes*, you should be able to deploy a XAP to any web server, IIS or otherwise.  The XAP runs on the client machine, so the web server is really just there to serve up the file.

Note that if your application references WCF services, those would require IIS.

Comment: indeed, this works like a charm, tested it myself. In some cases, you may need to add the mime type application/silverlight-2 to your web server in order to allow downloading the xap for clients.

Comment: With respect to WCF requiring IIS, that's actually not true. You *can* host WCF within IIS, but it's pretty trivial to write your own host as well, and there are sometimes good reasons to do so. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx.

Comment: @KenSmith - true enough.  However, Silverlight can be pretty picky about the WCF services it consumes and where/how they're hosted.

Answer (score 0):

One of the features we are introducing in Silverlight 4 is a ‘silent install’ mechanism for out-of-browser applications.  Currently every out-of-browser application (trusted or not) starts from an in-browser mechanism.  In some instances where you want to deploy the app via managed desktop software or perhaps via CD-ROM, you don’t want to have to tell the user to start on an HTML page first.

[Tim Heuer's blog](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/03/25/using-sllauncher-for-silent-install-silverlight-application.aspx)

has an example of how to create an installer for Silverlight Application.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification, this is an easy task with Silverlight.  It sounds like you want to install an out of browser application.  If Application.Current.InstallState == InstallState.NotInstalled, display a button that says "Install Me".  Provide a button click handler that simply calls [Application.Install](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.install%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).  Your application is now installed on the end user's client machine.